# Magento 2 : Can't edit simple product price in Admin Panel

Tags: product, magento2.4, price, catalog, edit

[image]

I have problem in Magento 2.4.6. I cannot edit the price of any simple product when selecting it in the `admin > Catalog > Product panel`. This does not happen in my local environment, nor in production, it only happens in pre-production, so I assume it is some environment problem. But I can't reproduce it. Im check the configurations, active modules and everything seems to be fine. Where would you start checking?

Comment: 1. Any error while admin page load? on consol or magento log files?

Comment: 2. When you click on "Advance Pricing" what it show to you?

Comment: @MageComp There's no need to insert "Magento 2" at the beginning of the titles since it is Magento's current major version and the tags can also reflect this. If you want, you can add/replace one of the tags with [magento2] though.